# Find each string in a list from a table column

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table that has about 1 million rows. One of the columns is a string, let's call it column A.

Now I need to work on a list L of about 1,000 strings, mostly one or two words, and I need to find all the records in the table where column A contains one of the 1,000 strings in the list L.

The only way I can think of is to use each string in L to do a full table scan, find if the string is a substring of column A content of each row. But that will be O(n2), and for a million rows it will take a very long time.

Is there a better way? Either in SQL or in C# code?

Comment: The table containing column A is in a database and the list L is in your C# program i suppose?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [full text index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc879306.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One million rows is a relatively small number these days. You should be able to pull all strings from column A, along with your table's primary key, into memory, and do a regex search using a very long regex composed from your 1000 strings:

```
var regex = new Regex("string one|string two|string three|...|string one thousand");
```

Since regex gets compiled into a final automaton, you would get reasonably fast scanning times for your strings. Once your filtering is complete, collect the IDs, and query full rows from the table using them.

Comment: I'm more familiar with this option so I choose this as answer to my question. But I'm sure other options are great too. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is is using linq. Lets say that you have your list

```
List<string> test = new List<string>{"aaa","ddd","ddsc"};
```

then using Linq you can constract

```
var match = YourTable.Where (t=> test.Contains(t.YourFieldName);
```

Comment: Please let me know if you'll need more explanation on this one

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms142571.aspx#like), it won't decrease the count of the operations you have to perform but it will increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you use Sql server (**you should always use the relevant tag to specify the rdbms**),
you can create a `DataTable` from your `List<string>` and send it to a stored procedure as a [table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Inside the stored procedure you can use a simple join of that table valued parameter to your table on database_table.col [contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787.aspx)(table_parameter.value) (using [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)).
Of course, things will go a lot faster if you create a [full text index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc879306.aspx) as suggested in the comments by [Glorfindel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel)